# URL mapping in Java Web Applications

Tags: java, spring, jsp

In a simple Java web application can we do JSP and HTML URL mapping in somewhat similar fashion to Spring's InternalResourceViewResolver, where we use prefix and suffix to map URLs.

Mapping should be done as following:-

```
mysite.com/home ==> /index.html
mysite.com/help ==> /help.html
mysite.com/view/form ==> /jsp/form.jsp
mysite.com/view/user ==> /jsp/user.jsp
```

I know that we can do JSP mapping in web.xml like:-

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>formpage</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/jsp/form.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>formpage</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/view/form</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But there is no prefix and suffix property here.

How can we generalize jsp and html mapping like above?

**Edit:**

Spring example:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Comment: What you are trying to ask ? Resources outside `web-inf` can be directly accessed . JSP files are pre-compiled in the server

Comment: I do not want to access them directly, currently I'm accessing a jsp page as `mysite.com/jsp/form.jsp` Now, I would now like access the same page with this URL `mysite.com/view/form`

Comment: you need to map it in `web.xml` as you posted . doesnt that work?

Comment: Yes it does, but I need a general rule as in Spring, see the example in the edited part.

Comment: You can check for servlet filters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did, A lot of Answers are quite good, but I need a pure Java Web Application solution and here is what I did:-

I created a Servlet Filter and the `doFilter` method is as follows:-

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    String uri = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI();
    String path = uri.replace(
            ((HttpServletRequest) request).getContextPath(), "");

    if (path.startsWith("/view/")) {
        String rd = path.replace("/view/", "/jsp/") + ".jsp";
        request.getRequestDispatcher(rd).forward(request, response);
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the rules for servlet mapping in the [specification document](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf) (page 115ff, which is 137ff in the PDF). You can use `*` as prefix or suffix but not inside of a path. As your mapping (as general rules; the specific ones could be created manually but I think that is not what you want) is not possible with this you need to either use another solution (like Spring; the dispatcher servlet was created exactly because of this limitation) or provide your own default servlet that does this for you.

Answer (score 0):

What I did once upon a time (12 yrs ago) was that I created my custom dispatcher servlet and make it handle all actions.

```
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then my controller had external [configuration file](http://git.abclinuxu.cz/?p=abclinuxu.git;a=blob;f=conf/url_mapping.xml;h=075dd59c70655272e0c2ffc5cbfeb13e64da51b6;hb=HEAD) with mapping rules:

```
<mapping>
     <pattern>^/$</pattern>
     <action>cz.abclinuxu.servlets.html.view.ViewIndex</action>
</mapping>
```

The [Controller servlet](http://git.abclinuxu.cz/?p=abclinuxu.git;a=blob;f=src/cz/abclinuxu/servlets/Controller.java;h=201d02d9bae342e4e4ab42cd2db9bd87033b0ceb;hb=HEAD) and [HTMLVersion](http://git.abclinuxu.cz/?p=abclinuxu.git;a=blob;f=src/cz/abclinuxu/servlets/html/HTMLVersion.java;h=e654b261ef8aa2bc296ed84793bd093536aadf40;hb=HEAD)

```
 protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
     URLMapper urlMapper = URLMapper.getInstance(URLMapper.Version.HTML);
     if ( urlMapper.redirectDeprecated(request, response) )
         return;

     AbcAction action = urlMapper.findAction(request, response, env);
     if (action == null)
         return;
```

You may get inspired or seek for web framework that does it for you.

Comment: @Kaushik - do you need more info?

Answer (score 0):

Now, 
 if you want to access view should be like  mysite.com/view/form instead ofmysite.com/jsp/form.jsp

make the url pattern in web.xml  as  below

```
 <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

In the controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/view/form")
public class FormController {

 /* actual Code here 
 */
}
```